# Resetting a Vue.js list order of all items after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, vue.js

I have a drag and drop component (using Sortable) but I can't figure out the logic to update the list order once the the item is dropped into it's new location.

Code (Vue.js):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#dragdrop',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        {name: 'Item 1', id: 1, order: 0}, 
        {name: 'Item 2', id: 2, order: 1}, 
        {name: 'Item 3', id: 3, order: 2}, 
        {name: 'Item 4', id: 4, order: 3}, 
        {name: 'Item 5', id: 5, order: 4}, 
        {name: 'Item 6', id: 5, order: 5}, 
       ],
    }
  },
  ready() {
    Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sort'), {
      draggable: 'li.sort-item',
      ghostClass: "sort-ghost",
      animation: 80,
      onUpdate: function(evt) {
        console.log('dropped (Sortable)');
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    dropped() {
      console.log('dropped (Vue method)');
    }
  }
});
```

I have a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jackbarham/rubagbc5

I'm looking to get the `order` in the array to sync up so I can make an AJAX update once the item is dropped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but I think it works. This uses the Sortable `onUpdate` handler to update the underlying array. Whenever an item is dragged to a new position, it gets moved to the same location in the array - this way the view model stays in sync with what's displayed in the view. Then the item `order` properties get updated to match their new positions in the array.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#dragdrop',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        {name: 'Item 1', id: 1, order: 0}, 
        {name: 'Item 2', id: 2, order: 1}, 
        {name: 'Item 3', id: 3, order: 2}, 
        {name: 'Item 4', id: 4, order: 3}, 
        {name: 'Item 5', id: 5, order: 4}, 
        {name: 'Item 6', id: 6, order: 5}, 
       ],
    }
  },
  ready() {
    var vm = this;
    Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sort'), {
      draggable: 'li.sort-item',
      ghostClass: "sort-ghost",
      animation: 80,
      onUpdate: function(evt) {
        console.log('dropped (Sortable)');
        vm.reorder(evt.oldIndex, evt.newIndex);
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    reorder(oldIndex, newIndex) {
      // move the item in the underlying array
      this.list.splice(newIndex, 0, this.list.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
      // update order properties based on position in array
      this.list.forEach(function(item, index){
        item.order = index;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You can optimize the `reorder()` method if you need to.

Here's an [updated version of your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peterburrell/rubagbc5/5/).

I feel like this is the kind of functionality that one should try to package up into a custom directive but I haven't figured out exactly how to do that yet.

Comment: IMO, this example should be within the draggable documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Vue.js ic directive to handle this kind of update in a generic way.
It can be used exactly as v-for directive but add the drag and drop capacity and corresponding updates on the view model array.

**Usage:**

```
<div v-dragable-for="element in list">{{element.name}}</div>
```

**Demo:**

[image: Example].

Fiddle: [example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/j62g58z7/), [example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/hqxranrd/)

GitHub: [Vue.Dragable.For](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.Dragable.For)